# Display one to many Records on datagrid

Tags: extjs, extjs7

can check whether anyone has any solution to display multiple rows from the records

Student Model

- name
- studentid
- address

```
Ext.define('Student',{
  extend: 'Ext.data.model',

  requires: [
    'Ext.data.field.Field'
  ],
  uses: [
    'Course'
  ],
  fields: [
    {
      mapping : 'name',
      name: 'name'
    },
    {
      mapping : 'studentid',
      name: 'studentid'
    },    
    {
      mapping : 'address',
      name: 'address'
    }
  ],
  hasMany: {
    associatedName: 'Course',
    model: 'Course',
    name: 'Course'
  }
});
```

Course Model

- courseid
- coursename
- coursecode

```
Ext.define('Course', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

  requires: [
    'Ext.data.field.Field'
  ],
  uses: [
    'Student'
  ],
  fields: [
    {
      mapping: 'Student.courseid',
      name: 'courseid'
    },    
    {
      mapping: 'Student.coursename',
      name: 'coursename'
    },    
    {
      mapping: 'Student.coursecode',
      name: 'coursecode'
    },
  ],
  belongsTo: {
    associatedName: 'Student',
    model: 'Student',
    name: 'Student'
  }
});
```

below is the data records

```
{
"name": "John",
"studentid": "122", 
"address": "111 XXX Road" ,
"course"[
 {
  "courseid":"1",
  "coursename":"Math",
  "coursecode":"MATH1"
 },
 {
  "courseid":"2",
  "coursename":"English",
  "coursecode":"ENG1"
 },
 {
  "courseid":"3",
  "coursename":"Science-Chemistry",
  "coursecode":"CHEMI"
 }
]
}
```

i wish to display the course details on grid as below

COURSECODE     COURSENAME

1. MATH1          Math
2. ENG1           English
3. CHEMI          Science-Chemistry

Currently i only able to display one row on the datagrid base on the renderer

```
columns:[
  {
     xtype: 'gridcolumn',
     renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
         return record.course().first().get('coursecode');
     },
     dataIndex: 'course.coursecode',
     text: 'Course Code'
  },
  {
     xtype: 'gridcolumn',
     renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
         return record.course().first().get('coursename');
     },
     dataIndex: 'course.coursename',
     text: 'Course Name'
  },
]
```

Result Now is this

COURSECODE     COURSENAME

1. MATH1          Math

Comment: Do you want to display only courses (3 in the example) or also student data in the grid?

Comment: Hi @PeterKoltai, i wish to display only the course in the grid. does extjs support display student data in grid with nested object??

Comment: You can use `course` as the store for the grid and then you don't need the renderers, just simply set `dataIndex` like `coursecode` etc. The best is to create different models for student and course and set up one to many association.

Comment: @PeterKoltai, my current implementation is create two model (student, course) and set one to many association. but seem like i unable display the coursecode in grid.

Comment: If you update your question with the current code, including models etc. I will have a look at it.

Comment: @PeterKoltai : i have update the model code

Comment: @nngjiajun And does it work? I mean if you load a user, do you have the courses as a store when accessing like `user.courses()`? I think simply `hasMany: 'Course'` is enough and you don't need 'Student.' in mapping, [check here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.data.schema.Association.html) under `Keyless associations`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your implementation you could use:

```
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
        const courseStore = record.course();
        let subview = '';
        
        courseStore.each(function(singleCourseRecord) {
            subview += '<p>' + singleCourseRecord.get('coursecode') + '</p>;
        });

        return subview;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Dinkheller, can i check with you, can the renderer show the row each individually like this example i created  (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3hlt&view/editor)

Comment: Can you upload an image of how it should look like in the end or send to sencha-mvp@m-gd.com?